# Imprimindo com nome do caminho salvo numa tabela

Tags: microsoft-access, relatório

Criei uma tabela chamada `Funcionarios` onde eu tenho pelo menos 2 campos:

`ID` e `caminho_impressao`.

Onde eu coloco por exemplo:

1. C:\Users\usuario1\documents\
2. C:\Users\usuario2\documents\

Dai eu tentei imprimir um PDF de um relatório da seguinte forma:

```vb
Dim FileNamePDF As String
Dim SetDirectoryPDF As String
Dim strRelatorio As String

    
' set directory to save to
SetDirectoryPDF = DLookup("caminho_impressao", "Funcionarios", "ID=" & login.ID)

'set the filename and save location
strRelatorio = "Relatorio_mensal"
'Tentei e não deu
'FileNamePDF = SetDirectoryPDF & strRelatorio & ".pdf"
FileNamePDF = CStr(SetDirectoryPDF) & strRelatorio & ".pdf"
MsgBox FileNamePDF
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strRelatorio, acFormatPDF, FileNamePDF, False
```

Mas não consegui gerar o arquivo. Aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: Captura de Tela]

## Pergunta

Como posso lidar com este erro em particular?

Comment: Uma dúvida: o que é exibido na chamada 'MsgBox FileNamePDF'?  Pergunto isso, pois o erro pode ser devido a algo errado no caminho/nome do arquivo de saída.

Comment: Aliás, pergunta boba (eu sei), mas o caminho existe?

Comment: Na verdade já resolvi o problema, estava tudo correto, eu só precisava compactar e corrigir o bd, dai tudo funcionou perfeito.

Comment: Que bom então! Que tal você adicionar uma resposta com as suas conclusões? Isso pode ajudar alguém mais no futuro. :)

Comment: Você poderia colocar a solução aqui pra gente aprender também?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'Imprimir todos os relatórios

Dim FileNamePDF As String
Dim SetDirectoryPDF As String
Dim strRelatorio As String

'Tabela Funcionarios contem pelo menos os campos: ID, Nome, caminho_impressao
SetDirectoryPDF = DLookup("caminho_impressao", "Funcionarios", "ID=" & login.ID)

strRelatorio = "Orcamentos"
FileNamePDF = SetDirectoryPDF & strRelatorio & ".pdf"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strRelatorio, acFormatPDF, FileNamePDF, False

strRelatorio = "Vendas"
FileNamePDF = SetDirectoryPDF & strRelatorio & ".pdf"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strRelatorio, acFormatPDF, FileNamePDF, False

strRelatorio = "Contratos"
FileNamePDF = SetDirectoryPDF & strRelatorio & ".pdf"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strRelatorio, acFormatPDF, FileNamePDF, False

MsgBox "Os arquivos foram salvos na pasta Bibliotecas\Documentos.", vbInformation, ""
```

Em caminho_impressao eu defino o caminho de cada máquina (funcionário), exemplo,

```
C:\Users\vendedor01\documents\
```

Na verdade, o código estava correto desde antes, mas só corrigiu quando eu pedi para *'Compactar e Reparar...'*